# Create test which add country code in a loop

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I need to create a test which will have base URL (**https://www.horisen.com**) and added part with country code (i.e **https://www.horisen.com/se**). Problem for me is there are 12 countries to be changed. 
I tried to create **if** loop without any success.
So, in summary, I have to go through all 12 different languages, open those pages in current languages, and continue with next lang. I suppose that I need an array of 12 country codes and call that in a loop, but do not know how to acchieve this.
Thank you in advance

```
String url = htps://www.horisen.com/
int[] array;

array = new int[6];

array[0] = de;
array[1] = se;
array[2] = dk;
array[3] = fr;
array[4] = en;
array[5] = fi;

for(int i=0; i++) {
do not know how to add after string url country code on the ned
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time, please put some actual java code (that compiles) in your example. Perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
    String url = "https://www.horisen.com/";
    String[] countryCodes = {"de", "se", "dk", "fr", "en", "fi"};
    for (String countryCode : countryCodes) {
        String countryUrl = url + countryCode;
        System.out.println(countryUrl);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Stefan. Something like that I was looking for